# Multiple instances of chrome in nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-devtools

I'm reading a list of urls from a file and then for each url I first launch chrome and then navigate to that page and record some tracing events.

```
var chromeLauncher = require('chrome-launcher')
var Chrome = require('chrome-remote-interface')
function launchChrome(Someurl){
   chromeLauncher.launch({
     //ports, flags
     }).then((launcher) => {
         Chrome(function(chrome){
            Tracing.Start();
            chrome.Page.navigate(SomeUrl)
            Tracing.Complete();
         });
       });

urlList.on('line', (line) => {
   launchChrome(line)
});
```

However since Chrome is an async function we have multiple chromes being launched simultaneously before tracking begins.
I want the chrome instances to fire in sequence, open url , track and exit.